# How to get swap size in Linux from /proc/swaps?

Tags: java, linux, jsf

I want to develop JSF page which can display the swap size if the operating system is Linux and what percentage is utilized. I found that this information can be read from /proc/swaps. But when I open it I get this

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition   2047992 0   -1
```

How I can get just there values - 2047992 and 0? I know how to read the content of a text file. For example:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        process(str);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

And the other more advanced question is what if I have two swaps?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to parse the file, here is one implementation...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\/A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\s]+([a-z]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([\\-0-9]+).*");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/swaps"));
String s = reader.readLine();
while (s!= null){                
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    }
    s = reader.readLine();
}            
reader.close();
```

Comment: Using JNI to call sysinfo is probably a more robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

The (Linux-specific) system call `sysinfo(struct sysinfo* info)` fills in `info` with the following:

```
struct sysinfo {
    long uptime;             /* Seconds since boot */
    unsigned long loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    unsigned long totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
    unsigned long freeram;   /* Available memory size */
    unsigned long sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    unsigned long bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    unsigned long totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    unsigned long freeswap;  /* swap space still available */
    unsigned short procs;    /* Number of current processes */
    unsigned long totalhigh; /* Total high memory size */
    unsigned long freehigh;  /* Available high memory size */
    unsigned int mem_unit;   /* Memory unit size in bytes */
    char _f[20-2*sizeof(long)-sizeof(int)]; /* Padding for libc5 */
};
```

Of which `totalswap` and `freeswap` might be what you are after.

I don't know how you do native platform invocation in Java, but this is a good alternative to parsing the `/proc/swaps` file yourself.

## EDIT:

I played a bit with [JNA](http://www.github.com/twall/jna) and came up with this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;

public class Test {


    public interface CStdLib extends Library {
        static class SysInfo extends Structure {
            public NativeLong uptime;
            public NativeLong[] loads = new NativeLong[3];
            public NativeLong totalram;
            public NativeLong freeram;
            public NativeLong sharedram;
            public NativeLong bufferram;
            public NativeLong totalswap;
            public NativeLong freeswap;
            public short procs;
            public NativeLong totalhigh;
            public NativeLong freehigh;
            public int mem_unit;
            /* some padding? */
        }
        int sysinfo(SysInfo info);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CStdLib c = (CStdLib)Native.loadLibrary("c", CStdLib.class);
        CStdLib.SysInfo s = new CStdLib.SysInfo();
        c.sysinfo(s);
        System.out.println("totalram: " + s.totalram);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately you're going to have issues where the value is too large for a signed `long` and thus you might get the wrong value in Java, which I am seeing when trying to read the swap values on my machine.

Hope this helps!  (Caveat: I have never been confused with a Java programmer `:)` )

Comment: Very good answer! Unfortunately I'm new to Java and I don't know to write the code in Java. Maybe I can use JNI.

Comment: Is there other useful system call for monitoring Linux performance? For example number of total network sessions?

Comment: As far as I see from the Github page JNA is for Windows?

Comment: JNA runs on 'most platforms that support Java.'  The example I posted above runs on my Linux amd64 machine.